# Pergunta com solicitação de edição de resposta pode ficar em evidência automaticamente?

Tags: debate, edição

Essa pergunta foi feita há 2 anos atrás, foi modificada, e está em evidência.

Percebi que foi uma edição automática.
Segue o texto:

> `[Edit removed during grace period]`[

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/14727/3

Ela deve ser traduzida para o português, e o mais importante é o seguinte, é correta uma pergunta ficar em evidência assim de forma automática? Ela ainda tem uma resposta aceita.

Comment: Primeira vez que vejo isso, ainda mais numa pergunta tão antiga.

Comment: Relacionado : http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4408/t%c3%b3picos-antigos-trazidos-a-home-deveriam-ter-alguma-diferencia%c3%a7%c3%a3o

Comment: Qualquer edição vai pra home. Isso aí não é uma edição automática, o usuário @ZebraDoMal editou a postagem, e desfez as alterações dentro do prazo limite. **Basta ver que fiz o mesmo aqui no seu post**: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/5144/revisions

Comment: Dá pra salvar a pergunta editando e perguntando o que foi que aconteceu nesse caso. Só não editei eu mesmo pois não sei se vai representar a intenção do @Durtto

Comment: @Bacco ainda sim vale uma resposta sua não?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vide comentário acima :) - se for o que ele quer, pode editar a pergunta, e eu acho legal ficar no site para referencia futura. Até prefiro (independente de quem vai responder). Do jeito que está, ficou confuso o título em relação ao corpo da pergunta, além da premissa errada.

Comment: @Bacco que nó que você deu na minha cabeça...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A mensagem diz:

```
[Edit removed during grace period]
```

Primeiro, o que é *grace period*? É o período que você tem para modificar a pergunta ou resposta várias vezes de forma que todas essas modificações acabem sendo consolidadas em uma única edição. Este período é de 5 minutos*. Isso significa que assim que você começa a editar uma pergunta ou resposta, todas as edições que você fizer dentro de 5 minutos serão apresentadas no histórico como uma só.

Entretanto, se você fizer alterações, e então dentro deste período de 5 minutos as desfizer, como é que fica o histórico? O resultado é que a sua edição acaba sendo removida (nada mais justo, afinal você mesmo as desfez em menos de 5 minutos). O que sobra da sua edição fantasma é esse aviso *[Edit removed during grace period]*.

Ou seja, essa edição não foi feita por um bot. Foi feita e desfeita rapidamente pelo usuário HiHello, que é o autor da pergunta.

Porém, concordo que a mensagem deveria estar traduzida para o português.

<sub>* - Exceto que se uma outra pessoa fizer algum comentário, postar uma resposta para uma pergunta no *grace period* ou também editar a mesma pergunta ou resposta pouco depois que você o tenha feito, então o *grace period* é abortado.</sub>

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.